# How to add my own custom places at autocomplete Places search box?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have implemented autocomplete search box. From here,
[Places search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)
I have seen this question, [how-to-display-custom-places-in-google-maps-api-search-results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824133/how-to-display-custom-places-in-google-maps-api-search-results)
But it was unable to help me. The accepted answer is not showing custom places in auto completed result.

Now I want to show also my own custom places (from a JSON list of places) along with Google's place suggestion at autocomplete result. How can I implement this?

[image: Place box search]

Comment: @Kreloch the accepted answer is not showing suggestion in the autocomplete list. Can you provide a explanation?

Comment: I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27155447/3001970) which provides a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/seifeddinebesbes/wpp07xn0/) for a static item in the result list... But I guess you are looking more for an option really to search through you own list, right?

Comment: @wittich yes I have my own list, I have seen your example also. Still looking for solution.